# SQL Server export, back-up without to stop the server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can anyone tell me how can I make back-up to a database to to export it to a different database (SQL Server or mysql) without to stop the server ?

Comment: can you give a hint what sql server you are using?

Comment: Taking a backup or exporting data should never involve stopping the server! Are you talking about exporting to a different RDBMS ie Microsoft SQL Server to My SQL or how to do it from one Microsoft SQL Server instance to another Microsoft SQL Server instance)

Comment: did you get the answer you were looking for?  If so, could you please accept it?  If not, could you clarify what you are still looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Sql Server to Sql Server**

- Get a copy of your database: [Backup Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865.aspx)
- Restore a copy of your database: [Restore Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858.aspx)

```
    --when connected to source db instance
    BACKUP DATABASE AdventureWorks2008R2 
     TO DISK = 'Z:\SQLServerBackups\AdvWorksData.bak'

    --when connected to target db instance
    RESTORE DATABASE AdventureWorks2008R2
       FROM DISK = 'Z:\SQLServerBackups\AdvWorksData.bak'
```

**Sql Server to MySQL**

As far as I know, there aren't any standard methods for this.  It's a by hand, or by hand written program.  If I were tasked with this, I would try : SSMS, select a database, export data- source = sql server instance.  If there is a my sql destination available, maybe that will create the table structure for you automajically.  Else, I'm betting
 - you'll have to create the mysql schema, then pump the data over yourself
 - or there is some 3rd party tool someone is happy to sell you to assist you in the task.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I almost forgot that someone(you) helped me to sort out my problem :)